# Why are some daemons not labeled as gods?

Tags: greek, daemon

The original meaning (and spelling) of daemon was [inferior god](http://daemonpage.com/socrates-daimon.php) (lesser deity). Kind of like titan meaning [Stretchers or Strainers](http://mythagora.com/bios/ouranos.html). Daemones are also called personified spirits.

Examples:

- Agathodaemon is called a daemon.
- Cacodaemon is called a daemon.
- Sophrosyne is called a goddess.
- Mnemosyne is called a goddess.
- Phobos and Demos are called both.
- Pseudologos is called a deamon.
- Nike is called a goddess.

What are some called one but not the other?

Comment: In your examples, you seem to be mixing terms for groups of spirits (e.g. agathodemons & cacodemons), with names for singular deities (e.g. Sophrosyne, Mnemosyne). The question of what is a daemon and what is not is an interesting one, but I think your examples are more confusing than helpful. Also, it would be helpful if you could quote the definitions of daemon and titan from your links.